# Problems ordering my collection with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following:

```
var cities = _cityRepository.GetPk(partitionKey);
var sortedCities = cities.OrderBy(item => item.RowKey.Substring(0, 4))
                         .ThenBy(item => item.ShortTitle);
return sortedCities;
```

Where cities is: `ICollection<City>`

This is giving me an error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<Storage.Models.City>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Storage.Models.City>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Can someone help me out with this. I thought I can just run LINQ to reorder.

Answer (score 4):

add `.ToList()` at the end as below

```
var sortedCities = cities.OrderBy(item => item.RowKey.Substring(0, 4))
                         .ThenBy(item => item.ShortTitle).ToList();
```

probably your method has to return `IOrderedEnumerable`

Answer (score 1):

"Can't cast to specified type", call `.ToList`:

```
var sortedCities = cities.OrderBy(item => item.RowKey.Substring(0, 4))
                                  .ThenBy(item => item.ShortTitle).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method seems to expect a return value of type `ICollection<Storage.Models.City>` but you are returning an `IOrderedEnumerable<Storage.Models.City>` which is more generally a `IEnumerable<Storage.Models.City>`.

You can either change the return type of your method or convert your return value into something that is an `ICollection` such as a `List` with `ToList()`.